# is there no way to block spam coming from variable new users with the same nonsense?

Tags: discussion

The past days spam appears under variable user names. Is there no way to block it? IP addresses? phone numbers in content?

I just got a response when i tried to post only the first sentence that :

> This post does not meet our quality standards.

How could those stupidities pass quality standards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I just woke up and saw this wall of spam. I'm killing it with fire now, and I've requested blacklisting/IP banning (whichever the comm team deems necessary).

Note that the quality standards are more lenient for longer posts. A short post is more likely to fail the quality standards. They probably *should* catch such posts, but these are after all just computer algorithms, and have limits.

If you want to help, just spam flag these (6 spam flags leads to an auto deletion), or post in chat. I'll try to get as many as I can myself.

Comment: thanks, did not know the auto deletion.

Comment: Neither did I. I'll flag'em all.

Comment: thanks for the tip.